# How to log a lazy evaluated dataframe in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

How to do logging in Spark applications without triggering an action in logger statements?

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
df = df
  .logInfo("value is " + col("xyz));
```

Is it possible in Java?

Answer (score 0):

When I read your pseudo code, I read that you are going to log some elements of the column (5? 10?)… how do you expect the element to render in the log file? Visual ASCII array like `show()`?

What I have done in similar cases is call the first record and simply show it on the console, as in:

```
df.show(1);
```

It won’t evaluate the whole data in the DAG. If you need to access the values themselves use:

```
Row r = df.first();
log.debug(r.mkString());
```

Look at: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#mkString-java.lang.String-

I assumed df was an instance of `Dataset<Row>`.